# Problem connecting Cisco VPN 5 through router

Tags: cisco-vpn-client

I'm using XP and a dlink router (DI-634M) at home (firmware is 2.02 from 10/2006). I just upgraded my Cisco VPN from 4.8 to 5.0 and since, I can't connect.
I managed connecting around the router - but this isn't a good solution.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check if there's an update to the router's firmware.
If you're having troubles finding it, let me know its model number so I can help.

Comment: I have a dlink DI-634M. I have firmware: 2.0 from 2005. I'll try upgrading. Thanks

Comment: ok. uploaded the latest firmware - 2.02. Still didn't work.. Other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using the help of: http://www.dslreports.com/forum/remark,14905503
The answer is to switch the transport from IP/UDP to IP/TCP. It might be a workaround but it does the trick.